# Detect sql action after a find_or_create_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Consider this `Rails` code:

```
town = Town.find_or_create_by_name("Paris")
```

How can I know if `town` was just inserted or if it already existed in the db?

Answer (score 0):

town = Town.find_or_create_by_name("Paris"). It will return a field having name="paris" if it field is exist, otherwise create an field having name="paris".

**How can I know if town was just inserted or if it already existed in the db?**

```
town = Town.find_by_name("Paris")
unless town.present?
    Town.create(:name=>'Paris')
end
```

Hope, It will solve your problem.

Comment: nope. Thx anyway. I know how find_or_create_by is working. I'm just asking if we can - through the instance - get the information about the query executed.